# How to avoid google api spreadsheets incompatibility with calendar

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api-java-client, google-sheets-api

In my GAE/J project I am attempting to use Google APIs, Spreadsheets and Calendar.

But Spreadsheets API CONTAINER includes the google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar that includes an older version of the Joiner class.

Calendar requires a newer version of it (with the on() method), that comes with the guava-jdk5-13.0.jar, that is in the Calendar API CONTAINER.

When Calendar code runs, the Joiner class has been resolved (to be the older version) and fails with a NoSuchMethod error.

This means that they are incompatible. I have tried multiple classpath settings with no luck. Spreadsheet access works, but then Calendar access fails.

Anyone else seen this and got a workaround?

Comment: If you switch to the Drive API, you won't have to worry about switching back and forth between the GData library and `google-api-java-client`. IIRC, the Spreadsheets API is deprecated anyhow.

Comment: bossylobster - the spreadsheet api v3.0 is here, only v1 & v2 are deprecated: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/ (I find it faster than Google apps script, although GAS has a better range of functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try deleting the Joiner class from google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar - I have deleted classes from a few jar files, not very clean, but works fine.

Comment: This is what I did in the end, using JarPlug BTW. It's not so robust to changes in the version of Spreadsheets API and the JAR Eclipse manages...but works.

Answer (score 1):

'google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar is deprecated and has been replaced by the 'guava' jar which is described here:
https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained

problem is that, as the OP states, some Google API's are indeed incompatible and need some very careful handling.  For example Google Spreadsheets API still comes packaged with google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar

for more info see:
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/issues/detail?id=344

here's what I did to get Calendars(Oauth) to work with Spreadsheets (using client libs):

- don't use the Eclipse plugin to manage Google API's - I found that it worked in DEV but as soon as I deployed to GAE it didn't work, I think because the deploy process copies jars found in the directory it uses: '.google_apis/'  - this causes runtime errors such as:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.of([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;

Managing jars manually also enables you to switch out jars where necessary, as described above.

- not all versions of the 'java client' libraries are the same, even though they may share the same name, e.g. 'gdata-client-1.0.jar'  You need to use a new one if you want it to depend on Guava and not the old collections jar : (i.e. 1.4.7.1 - download here https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/)
- be careful to manually remove and re-copy your jars into war/WEB-INF/lib as eclipse won't fully manage this for you (especially if you're updating a jar of the same name)
- finally, a tip to help track down runtime errors by resolving which files you are sourcing your dependencies from:

> System.out.println("URL: " + 
>                       Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource( 
>                       "com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.class"));

Comment: To expand on:   "I found that it worked in DEV but as soon as I deployed to GAE it didn't work" ---- the order jars are loaded can change, the load orders causes GAE problems. When 2 versions of a class exist in the jar files it can cause GAE to try and use the wrong version of the class.