# NoClassDefFoundError with Google Spreadsheets APIs on Google Application Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-sheets

I'm using the gdata-java-client from Google to work with Google spreadsheets.

```
SpreadsheetService s = new SpreadsheetService("myAppName");
```

This works in Eclipse. As soon as I run it on App Engine (dev environment), I get `NoClassDefError`.

The following jars are in `WEB-INF/lib`

- gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0.jar
- gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar
- jsr305.jar
- google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar
- gdata-client-1.0.jar

Instantiate other objects from those jars such as `SpreadsheetEntry` for example works. The solutions I've found for this problem lied all in missing jars. I think this isn't the problem here, since I could create other objects from those jars.

Comment: Which class is not found?

Comment: @Andrei Volgin I'm not sure. SpreadsheetService or one of its superclasses. The constructor is not even called. Might be a problem with static initializers?

Comment: Copy the error message here. It must tell you which class is not found. This error indicates a missing jar - we just need to find out which one.

Comment: It's the GoogleService class.

Comment: Thanks for your help!    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdata/client/GoogleService
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
 at ......
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: Thanks @AndreiVolgin! You kept me looking :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the problem was the Google Eclipse Plugin I used to manage the spreadsheet API. I got the hint from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212252/how-to-avoid-google-api-spreadsheets-incompatibility-with-calendar).

After adding following jars to  `WEB-INF/lib` and adding those to the classpath it finally works.

- gdata-core-1.0.jar
- gdata-client-1.0.jar
- gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar
- gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0.jar
- guava-11.0.2.jar
- jsr305.jar

Comment: Use the latest guava version.